# Save the filter value in a variable? Backpack / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

After applying a filter, I need to save the url value and automatically show it in a field when a new communication ("+ Aggiungi comunicazione") is created.
Can you help me? Thx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the Referer url on the `setupCreateOperation` with: `request()->headers->get('referer')`

**PLEASE** make sure you properly sanitize any input you get from the url, otherwise it could be a severe security issue.